# jQuery toggle not working when back button is hit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
    var linkSet = $('#link1').add('#link2');
    linkSet.click(function() {
    linkSet.toggle();
        if ($(this).attr('id')=='link1'){
        $('#frame').attr('src', 'www.google.com');
        } else if ($(this).attr('id')=='link2'){
        $('#frame').attr('src', 'www.yahoo.com');
        }
    });
});
```

On pageload, the link with id `link1` is shown while `link2` is hidden. When the user click the `link1`, it will the `link1` then show the `link2` then vice versa. While toggle takes place, it also changes the source of an iframe which is named `frame`.

My problem here is when I hit back button, the content of the frame will go back to its previous content BUT the link are not changing. What did I missed here? Thanks in advance!

Note: The links are on a webpage, then inside that webpage is an iframe.

**EDIT:**

```
<div id="header">
<ul>
    <li><a id="link1" href=#">Link1</a>
    <li><a id="link2" href=#">Link2</a> 
</ul>
</div>
<div id="iframe">
    <iframe id="frame" src="www.google.com"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't put `$(function() {` inside of `$(document).ready(function() {` - they do the same thing, so nesting them is unnecessary/duplication

Comment: Any chance to see the actual page?

Comment: You have `;` missing after `('#link2')` - is that a typo here, or is it how it is in the code, as well?

Comment: @Figaro its a typo. Sorry. I will try to put some more codes.

Comment: @Ian that is noted. Thanks!

Comment: @Ian isn't `$(document).ready(function() {});` convention and considered best practice?

Comment: @agconti Well, I didn't say which one to use, I was just pointing out that nesting them was unnecessary. But yes, I would say that `$(document).ready(func...` is probably "better"...mainly because it reads better what it actually does. But of course, remember they do the exact same thing.

Comment: @Gerald, what browser are you testing your page in / what browsers are you targeting?

Comment: @Figaro been testing it with chrome

Comment: Found an answer. The official docs recognize both.`$(document).ready(function() {});` is the long version, and is good for explicitly letting people know that its jQuery, while `$(function()` { is a short hand version.  See documentation [here](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

Comment: @Gerald – WHAT version of Chrome? The reason I'm asking is because the solution would depend on the browser. If you have the latest browsers in mind that support `history.pushState`, it would all become much easier.

Comment: @Ian Nice, thanks for answering. I was unaware of the short hand version. +1.

Comment: @Figaro the latest version of chrome. I also tested it with IE8. Same results.

Comment: Basically, @Gerald, your code is fine, but it's not going to work for browser back and forward buttons, unless you write code specifically for those buttons. Andres's answer should point you in the right direction, even though using hashes in URL has been generally frowned upon lately. You could use your functionality for `history.pushState` enabled browsers only (that doesn't include IE8), and let it gracefully degrade for older browsers.

Comment: Here's a couple of resources for you: http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history - and you may also want to look into this library: https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/

Answer (score 1):

You mean when pressing the browser's back button right.

If so:

The issue is you need to have an event to trigger when the history changes, as that is the only easy way to respond to changes in history (such as when clicking the back button). Since the iframe url is indeed changing, it is therefore also affected by the back button naturally.

To get other non history based logic to work when pressing the back button and such...
There are two ways to do this. The new one is by using the history API, while the other more supported, and simpler way is by adding a hash to the url.

WHAT DOES THIS MEAN?

When you click the button you change the url with a hash. Like the url can become

'http://domain.com/blah/#myHash'

Then instead of doing your logic in the click, you do it when the hash changes. So this way as the user clicks back and/or forward the logic always runs fully.

I wrote an entire article about this technique a few months ago at http://andresgallo.com/2012/06/08/ajaxifying-the-web-the-easy-way/

Comment: if you don't need to support IE8, or don't mind adding a polifyll, i'd say use the newer history API.  Its better than using the old school hashes